# Validate US ZIP codes in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need to validate US zip code in Informatica.

ZIP code could be 5 numeric or 
                  9 numeric or 
                 10 numeric with hyphen (01234-5678)

2. If an empty position occurs, it should be filled with spaces

examples: 5 digit zip: '01234 '
          9 digit zip: '012345678 '
         10 digit zip: '01234_5678'

Pl guide me. Thx

Comment: For simple validation @Daniel's answer should work. If you need more sophisticated address validation, go check Informatica Marketplace. There's a bunch of different solutions, ranging from Mapplets to webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 validation ports, one to flag length is 5, 9 or 10, and one to determine characters held within the text

For length its easy, use Length (portname)

For characters held in the port you could replace all spaces and hyphens with 0 and then check if the result is numeric.